# PHPDoc for object made from array

Tags: php, phpdoc

I have config.php file with following rules:

```
return [

    'debug' => true,
    'db_debug' => true,

    'lang' => 'Eng',
    ...
```

And so on. When my app initializes, this file will be used in constructor of class that will turn this array into its properties:

```
class Config 
{
    public function __construct($config) {
        foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I write PHPDoc for its properties to see suggestions in PHPStorm while using config values like this (when I type `$config->` IDE will suggest config keys):

```
$config = new Config();
echo $config->lang //Eng
```

I saw this in Yii and I don't understand how did they do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@property` annotation in the class-level block to list the properties. Your IDE should then autocomplete even if they're not explicitly defined.

```
/**
 * @property int    $id    The ID of the thing
 * @property string $name  The name of the thing.
 * @property bool   $debug True to enable debugging.
 */
class Config
{
}
```